# I can not transfer storage to the server. laravel

Tags: laravel, storage

I have a problem with transferring the connected storage folder which is located in public on a global server. When I move files, skip the storage folder in public, so when I add it manually, I lose the link between the main storage folder.
Earlier, I did not have this problem, if someone comes into contact with this problem and knows how to solve it, I am asking for help, thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: you can create link with storage with the following command. 
`php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Yes, I know, and everything works fine in the locale, but I can not use the console on the server because it's just hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run artisan commands from code

```
Route::get('/sotage', function () {
    \Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```